# phonegap 3.5.0 external plugins not working

Tags: cordova

I seriously need help here. i have been trying to add a plugin to my phonegap android app 
for  sqllite and i did the following:

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin
```

it says it added sucessfully. when i check all the files involved i actually see it inside my project app.
 even inside the res/xml/config.xml as:

```
<feature name="SQLitePlugin">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.pgsqlite.SQLitePlugin" />
</feature>
```

After that i build the andoid app and i try to get the the installed plugin, but i cant find it, especially the javascript that is supposed to expose the java class to the application.

i have tried the following to see if i can atleast see function:

```
alert(window.sqlitePlugin);// and i get the message 'undefined' on the phone
alert(window.SqlitePlugin); //and i get the same. 
alert(cordovo.sqlitePlugin); // the same error message 'undefined' on the phone
```

when i run:

```
phonegap serve
```

i dont see the plugin's javascript file showing on the terminal. i only see the defaults.
i have actually tried all sorts i have even created multiple phonegap project to try out different plugins but it all resorts to the same thing.

I am almost about regreting using phonegap for the application, especially when i am almost through with it.

Please any suggestions/ working solution will be welcomed.

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked that the deviceReady() event is getting fired before using the plugins or any Device APIs?

Comment: As frank said you're waited for the deviceready to fire,right? Also have you added the cordova.js script??

Comment: @frank yes i have, in fact the app starts when the deviceready event has been instantiated.

Comment: @AtanuCSE yes the cordova.js script is added as well at the top

Comment: @user1556937 can you try to build and run the project with cordova commands(replace phonegap with cordova keyword). Are you running the commands in the following sequence. 1. `cordova create appname com.yourname.appname appname` 2.`cd appname` 3.`cordova platforms add android`
4.`cordova plugin add https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin` 5.`cordova build android`

Comment: @frank i tried it with cordova the way you specified and it worked. 
I then also tried it back  this time using the phonegap command with a new project and it also worked as well.
Now i am wondering where i have been wrong all this while. But one thing i noticed is that i had to 
install the debug apk on an android device to test it. So far i have not tested it on the phonegap developer 
app. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

having gone round in circles about the issue, here is what i did differently and it worked this time (i also got help from @frank). 
from the inception (create he project):

```
phonegap create <appname>
```

add the plugin

```
phonegap plugin add <plugin folder>
```

once the plugin adds successfully

build the project for your specific platform

```
phonegap build android
```

run the debug apk on an emulator or on a real device (make sure you have your device connected to your system)

```
phonegap run android
```

once the app has installed, run it and you should see your plugin working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this plugin does not auto initialize.

Add this line of code to your deviceReady function before you interact with the sqlitePlugin.

```
var initSqlitePlugin = cordova.require("com.brodysoft.sqlitePlugin.SQLitePlugin");
```

The plugin should attach itself to the window object, so you can refer to the plugin just as sqlitePlugin or window.sqlitePlugin.

Comment: i just tried it and it does not seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Are you using any other plugins? Do they work? If not, try adding another one to help see if the issue is isolated to all of cordova or just the single plugin.  If deviceReady isn't called, that means cordova is not working properly.

Comment: cordova works properly, start the app when the deviceready event has been set.Then i even had to add another plugin called the **PhoneDialer** plugin  and the same thing happened. i couldn't refer to the plugin when the deviceready event has been instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

For all I know, that's the problem:

```
phonegap serve
```

Using of any external plugins is not supported when you serve your application on a local server.